# Align text to the right side of a button radio

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a theme which have this section below , I want to align the text on the right side of a radio button, right now it below the radio button

Here is what I want: [image]

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/Jm2JR/181/

```
   <div class="delivery_options">
        <div class="delivery_option item" style="margin: 0px;padding: 0px;">
            <div>
                <label class="delivery-option-label" for="delivery_option_13687_0">
                    <div class="resume div div-bordered">
                        <div>
                            <div class="delivery_option_radio">
                                <input id="delivery_option_13687_0" class="delivery_option_radio" type="radio" name="delivery_option[13687]" data-key="233," data-id_address="13687" value="233,">
                            </div>

                            <div class="delivery_option_logo">
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                Kurier DHL (2-5dni roboczych)

                                <span class="delivery_option_price">
                                                                                                                                                    12,00 zł
                                                                                                                    </span>

                                <br>
                                <span class="best_grade best_grade_speed">The fastest</span>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end delivery_option -->
        <div class="delivery_option alternate_item" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; float: none;">
            <div>
                <label class="delivery-option-label" for="delivery_option_13687_1">
                    <div class="resume div div-bordered">
                        <div>
                            <div class="delivery_option_radio">
                                <input id="delivery_option_13687_1" class="delivery_option_radio" type="radio" name="delivery_option[13687]" data-key="234," data-id_address="13687" value="234,">
                            </div>

                            <div class="delivery_option_logo">
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                Kurier DHL - pobranie (2-5 dni roboczych)

                                <span class="delivery_option_price">
                                                                                                                                                    12,00 zł
                                                                                                                    </span>

                                <br>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end delivery_option -->
        <div class="delivery_option item" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; float: none;">
            <div>
                <label class="delivery-option-label" for="delivery_option_13687_2">
                    <div class="resume div div-bordered">
                        <div>
                            <div class="delivery_option_radio">
                                <input id="delivery_option_13687_2" class="delivery_option_radio" type="radio" name="delivery_option[13687]" data-key="235," data-id_address="13687" value="235,">
                            </div>

                            <div class="delivery_option_logo">
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                Odbiór osobisty - Showroom - Mokotowska 40/3, Warszawa (2-3 dni roboczych)

                                <span class="delivery_option_price">
                                                            Free
                                            </span>

                                <br>
                                <span class="best_grade best_grade_price">The best price</span>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end delivery_option -->
        <div class="delivery_option alternate_item" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; float: none;">
            <div>
                <label class="delivery-option-label" for="delivery_option_13687_3">
                    <div class="resume div div-bordered">
                        <div>
                            <div class="delivery_option_radio">
                                <input id="delivery_option_13687_3" class="delivery_option_radio" type="radio" name="delivery_option[13687]" data-key="231," data-id_address="13687" value="231," checked="checked">
                            </div>

                            <div class="delivery_option_logo">
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                Odbiór osobisty - Sklep - Stary Browar, Poznań (2-5 dni roboczych)

                                <span class="delivery_option_price">
                                                            Free
                                            </span>

                                <br>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end delivery_option -->
    </div>
```

I tried using float but didnt work, any idea or help, suggestion will be apreciated, please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add this line to your css

```
.resume > div {
   display: flex;
}
```